# Can TinyMCE 4.2.1 be installed under CiviCRM 4.1.5?

Tags: wysiwyg, tinymce

I have been attempting to install TinyMCE 4.2.1 as the default Drupal editor but have run into problems. I have posted separately on the TinyMCE forum about this. I am just wondering if anyone has installed it as a separate wysiwyg editor CiviCRM?

We are on 4.1.5

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM 4.1 is not maintained and highly insecure. Unless you have manually backported *every* security patch on [this list](https://civicrm.org/advisory) plus the relevant ones on [this list](https://civicrm.org/blogs/spidersilk/civicrm-security-releases-31-quick-reference-list) then you are strongly recommended to upgrade to a supported version. Recent versions, incidentally, ship with TinyMCE.